# Break out of a loop when running a Python program on the command line

Tags: python, command-line, while-loop

I know that using Ctrl+C can be used to exit from a running process when using the Windows command line but when I try this in order to break out of a while loop that asks for user input it doesn't work.

Here's the run() method for a small Black Jack game I'm making:

```
def run():
    print('\t==================== Welcome to the Black Jack Casino ====================\n')
    while True:
        try:
            player_chips = int(input('How many chips do you want to buy? '))
            break
        except:
            print('Don\'t muck me about... ')
    cash_out = False
    dealer = Dealer()
    player = Player()
    player.chips = player_chips
    while not cash_out or player.chips >= 0:
        try:
            player_bet = int(input('Place a bet: '))
            if player_bet > player.chips:
                print('You don\'t have the readies mate...')
            else:
                start_game(dealer, player, player_bet)
                try:
                    quit = input('You want to continue? (Y/N) ')
                    if quit.lower() == 'n':
                        cash_out = True
                except:
                    print('Don\'t talk rubbish...')
        except:
            print('Don\'t waste my time...')
            continue
    try:
        play_again = input('Fancy another game? (Y/N)')
        if play_again.lower() == 'y':
            run()
        else:
            print('Next time then sucker...')
            return
    except:
        print('Don\'t talk rubbish...')
```

When trying to Ctrl+C out of the while loop, it prompts me to 'Place a bet' and just prints 'Don't waste my time...'. How can I make this work because it's really annoying to keep quitting `cmd` and then re-navigating to my files. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make this work because it's really annoying to keep quitting cmd and then re-navigating to my files. Thanks

**Don't use bare `except`** (`except` statement without an exception type specified): in Python, Ctrl-C is converted to an exception and raised. This means `except` without any more information *will* catch it, and execute whatever exception handling code you defined.

In Python, you *almost always* want to explicitly catch `Exception` as it includes most exceptions but importantly excludes `KeyboardInterrupt` (which is what Ctrl-C translates to) and `SystemExit` (which is what `sys.exit()` triggers). See [the exceptions hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

The main exception to this is performing cleanup then re-raising directly, in that case a bare except is acceptable (though often unnecessary because if the process is killed you *usually* don't need to close files or the like).

Incidentally the same applies if you ever need to define your own exception: it should extend `Exception` unless it's a system-type exception which generally should not be caught and resumed from.

Answer (score 0):

Try and Except blocks are used for catching scenarios that are unprecedented or not accounted for a developer, Say

- You are accessing a file and somehow the file was deleted.
- You are accessing a database and connection was lost.
- You lost contact of something and you cannot predict how it will affect it.

The reason you are not being able to exit the program is because it catched an error and moving to except block which is how to handle it.

More Information : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

- So basically what I did in the code below is that we are telling it to exit incase you are giving a signal of keyboard interrupt (Ctrl + c ) to stop the program which is as below.
- The concept is called signal handling and is used in prod environments.
- You can my github link below for the source code :
  https://github.com/SugaanthMohan/Python_Tools/blob/master/SignalHandling/SignalHandling.py

If you want your code to stop only by keyboard Interrupt Ctrl+C, Use the code below.

```
def run():
    print('\t==================== Welcome to the Black Jack Casino ====================\n')
    while True:
        try:
            player_chips = int(input('How many chips do you want to buy? '))
            break
        except:
            print('Don\'t muck me about... ')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise SystemExit

    cash_out = False
    dealer = Dealer()
    player = Player()
    player.chips = player_chips
    while not cash_out or player.chips >= 0:
        try:
            player_bet = int(input('Place a bet: '))
            if player_bet > player.chips:
                print('You don\'t have the readies mate...')
            else:
                start_game(dealer, player, player_bet)
                try:
                    quit = input('You want to continue? (Y/N) ')
                    if quit.lower() == 'n':
                        cash_out = True
                except:
                    print('Don\'t talk rubbish...')
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    raise SystemExit
        except:
            print('Don\'t waste my time...')
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise SystemExit
    try:
        play_again = input('Fancy another game? (Y/N)')
        if play_again.lower() == 'y':
            run()
        else:
            print('Next time then sucker...')
            return
    except:
        print('Don\'t talk rubbish...')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise SystemExit
```